# Connect to a bluetooth printer, and print something

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth

The library i'm using is called [Plugin.BLE](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le). It doesn't have good documentation, and I'm just guessing.

First I scan for connected devices, then I connect to the bluetooth printer which is called "MTP-2" then I get it's service. From that service I get the characteristics, and I write data into it, but it doesn't actually do anything.

```cs
        private async void Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            var devices = adapter.GetSystemConnectedOrPairedDevices();
            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                var name = device.Name;
                if (name == "MTP-2")
                {
                    var cts = new CancellationToken();
                    var guid = device.Id;
                    await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, new ConnectParameters(true, true), cts);
                    var services = await device.GetServicesAsync();
                    foreach (var _service in services)
                    {
                        var characteristics = await _service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                        foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
                        {
                            var read = characteristic.CanRead;
                            var write = characteristic.CanWrite;
                            var update = characteristic.CanUpdate;
                            if (read && write && update)
                            {
                                await characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
                                var content = "Hi there.";
                                var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                                await characteristic.WriteAsync(data);
                                await characteristic.StopUpdatesAsync();

                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: maybe try it with ZPL (zebra printing language) commands, Here some docs https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: I'm not using their line of printers though. Even if I did, I went through their documentation about how it's made/structured. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: most of the current printers support ZPL, it is like an industrial standard

Answer (score 1):

I think you have such options:

1. send a special character to initiate printing. I think the printer should have some documentation for this.
2. call a special method from the api.

Comment: I went to the site where the printer was manufactured, and went to the "downloads" section. I went through every file, and all of time are either software to use the printer, or java doc. Which is irrelevant since I'm doing it in C#.

Comment: In this case i think you can write an email to the manufacturer.

Comment: I found a way to trigger printing. It's not via some special character. I just have to write to a socket that is connected to the bluetooth printer. With `_socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync()`